# In AWS EC2, how to find metadata of an instance that no longer exists?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using CloudTrail Events to reconstruct the last 90 days of EC2 usage history with high temporal resolution.

For some instances I know the ID but not the instance type (for example, because the log contains the TerminateInstance event but the preceding RunInstance event has expired). The DescribeInstances EC2 API operation returns a non-existence error (presumably because the instance with that ID terminated too long ago).

How can I find the instance-type for an instance that no longer exists, assuming I still know the instance-id?

Comment: If RunInstance has already expired, and you don't have any other external observability keeping track of that infra, I don't believe there is a way through the CLI/API or Cloudwatch. Do you have any logs or metrics from outside of Cloudwatch, or perhaps build logs from your CI system? Do you have Billing access on the AWS account? If so you should at least be able to see an instance-type breakdown under Bill Details By Service (unless that moved with the Console redesign).

Comment: @ZacAnger unfortunately Billing tends not to retain data at hourly or finer resolution (at least not for more than a week or so). That was my initial motivation - to separate trends in peak and baseline usage, to assess optimal Savings Plan sizing for a workload that fluctuates significantly.

Comment: @ZacAnger CloudWatch seems unable to be used to monitor counts of instances (except where the instances are produced exclusively by ASGs and no ASGs have been replaced recently), let alone to discover ids; are you saying it *can* be used to identify types (once ids are known)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can potentially be extracted from the config service.

The config service should be the authoritative source of information on an EC2 instance's status history. Even if the relevant API event history (the Run, Start, Stop and Terminate events) were complete, sometimes an instance may change state (e.g. shut itself down) without any external API event. The config service may also have a different retention period than CloudTrail.

```bash
aws configservice get-resource-config-history                             \
         --resource-type AWS::EC2::Instance                               \
         --resource-id i-XXXXXXX                                          \
         --max-items 2                                                    \
| jq '.configurationItems[1].configuration | fromjson | .instanceType'
```

Comment: Great find! From the API docs: "If you specified a retention period to retain your ConfigurationItems between a minimum of 30 days and a maximum of 7 years (2557 days), AWS Config returns the ConfigurationItems for the specified retention period." And from an update in 2018, "If you don’t specify a retention period, AWS Config continues to store configuration items for the default period of 7 years (2,557 days)."